# Is there a way to install all versions of all browsers on one machine?

Tags: testing, browser, installation

Is there a way to install all versions of all browsers on one machine?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you you mean by "all browsers'. Do you really want IE1, IE2, IE3, IE4, etc?

Answer (score 8):

I use virtual machines to do different browser version configurations.  I'm assuming you want to test different version of IE, Firefox etc.

If you automate your testing at any point the virtual machines are also handy for having a way to store many different configurations for testing on one machine.

Comment: You need to buy a license for every XP virtual machine, so unless you have a bulk license, or pirate, or have Vista (up to 4 VMs), this could get expensive

Answer (score 1):

Sure, and the best way to do this is to use virtualisation technology such as [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org).

Answer (score 1):

we have used this to install mutiple versions of IE for testing it goes as far back as 3.0

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

Comment: MultipleIEs has many problems, including issues with cookies and conditional comments.

Comment: Not to mention no support under Vista, which was the final deal-breaker for me. (Although prior to using Vista at work, I loved it.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/).  Much less work to deal with than a VM.  Probably will run faster.

Answer (score 1):

For several browsers, like Firefox or Opera, it is just a matter of copying the original program directory elsewhere and upgrading. Most of the time, the old version should still work.

For IE, there are several distributions, [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) seems to be a complete, easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

For FireFox, you can install the portable versions available [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)

With IE, I think the only way is via virtual machines. I can recommend VirtualBox, works smoothly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?

Typically, a product wont allow parallel installs (multiple versions of same product, though certainly you can have multiple versions of different products).

If you want to do some analysis or testing , doing that in separate Virtual Machines (check out VMWare) may be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you really want this but if you want to install different versions of IE use the following tool:

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

Answer (score -2):

Yes. I have IE8 Beta2, FF3, Chrome Beta, and Safari 3.1.2 with the applicable developer plugins.

Comment: I think he means multiple versions from each browser vendor.

Comment: All the repeating All's is Allways confusing to me. =/ (All)